# Unable to generate unassigned apk file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to generate an apk file from edit configurations / + / Gradle/ assemle but no file is generated. After editing the configurations, I tried to make project, rebuild and clean but there is nothing in the output folder. I also tryed to press Run but I get this error:

> Executing tasks: [assemble]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. NDK is missing a
>   "platforms" directory. If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set
>   to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to
>   C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle. If you are not
>   using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or
>   local.properties to remove this warning.
>
> NDK is missing a "platforms" directory. If you are using NDK, verify
>   the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to
>   C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle. If you are not
>   using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or
>   local.properties to remove this warning.
>
> Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':library:apklib'.
>
>   > Task with path 'packageReleaseJar' not found in project ':library'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.296 secs

Any idea what to do, to create apk file? I am a little lost.

I am using android studio 2.3.1 and gradle:2.3.1

Comment: Check Build Variant from side panel under project structure

Comment: Some of your library reference in project is giving that error. Check it out if you have used somethin

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha I can't find it,where is it exactly?And what to check when I find it?

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha ok I found it.

Comment: change build variant to Debug

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem, I was able to generate apk file from:

Build / Build Apk